# I'm trying to design a two-switch foward and found this gate drive design, can someone explain it to me?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, gate-driving

[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Noob questions below.

In the above square box is the gate drive circuit that I found and implemented into my circuit. It uses the same PWM and gate drive IC from Analog Devices.

1. How do I analyze the circuit in order to change the values for my design? My circuit analysis skills are not the strongest.
2. OUT1 appears to go to a pulsed XFMR, what are the BJTs and Zeners at the output for? Is this a level shift to configure a half-bridge drive?

Comment: Your graphs of signals are irrelevant with node names. Use proper names please i.e. name your nodes. Please also link to the source of the strange looking gate design.

Comment: Where did you find it? Someone who isn't very good at analog design, is my guess.

Answer (score 2):

A [two-switch forward](https://www.onsemi.cn/pub/Collateral/TND378-D.PDF) converter can be driven by a simple two-winding transformer a shown in the below figure excerpted from this [document](https://www.eeweb.com/wp-content/uploads/articles-app-notes-files-2-switch-forward-current-mode-converter-1495431887.pdf):

[image]

The circuit you try to simulate looks fairly complicated to me - unless I missed some important feature - and I believe you can simplify it as shown in the above. I've seen applications where a single-winding transformer was used for the high-side only (as in your circuit) but I prefer a two-winding approach for the drive symetry. A bootstrapped half-bridge circuit could also be used but an extra circuit is often needed to refresh the bootstrap capacitor.

The 2-switch converter is a robust structure and was popular in so-called silver boxes for ATX computers. This [site](https://danyk.cz/s_atx_en.html) does a good job for collecting many power supplies schematics which use a 2-SW forward.